# Android Make one request with post method, but it save 2 data in database

Tags: android

i want to asking about request in android. I made a request, but when executed, it stores 2 data in the database. I have no idea why this doesn't work well.

For information, i use php to handle request. and not only on my web apps. When i try using another web apps, it still save 2 data.

this is my code, thanks.

```html
public void sendToServer(){

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        StringRequest URL = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, storeCC, new Response.Listener<String>(){

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("SUKSES", response.toString());

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("error gan", error.toString());
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String, String> jsonParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonParams.put("poin", point);
                jsonParams.put("id_imei",id_imei);
                jsonParams.put("billingNm", name);
                jsonParams.put("harga", String.valueOf(amt));

                return jsonParams;

            }

        };
        RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(URL);

    }
```

Hope you help me.

Comment: you must me doing something wrong in your php service.! check your columns name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem may arise if you use "https".Add Handler over there and delay the request as Https often response late, Caution you have to manage every request.

```
Handler handler= new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Your code after 5 seconds delay
                sendToServer();
            }
        },5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution where **setRetryPolicy of Volley Request**:-

```
public void sendToServer(){

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, storeCC, new Response.Listener<String>(){

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("SUKSES", response.toString());

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("error gan", error.toString());
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String, String> jsonParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
            jsonParams.put("poin", point);
            jsonParams.put("id_imei",id_imei);
            jsonParams.put("billingNm", name);
            jsonParams.put("harga", String.valueOf(amt));

            return jsonParams;

        }

    };

    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5*1000,-1,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));    

    RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

}
```